# how to restore all files using trash-restore ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04

How to restore all files from trash using trash-restore ?

```
What file to restore [0..8688]:
```

I am using ubuntu 20.04 (gnome) and if using nautilus to restore.... it freze and that's why I am trying to use the cli restore .... but I don't know how to restore them all.

I have tried * and it says invalid entry.

Comment: Currently looking for an answer on this as well. Using Dolphin is so painfully slow and buggy that I need a streamlined version.